# Flutter Websockets MacOS: The same code works in debug mode but not in release mode: "(OS Error: nodename nor servname provided..)"

Tags: flutter, macos, dart, websocket

#### Summary

I have a program using WebSockets in Flutter, the program is fully functional in *debug* mode, but running the same *exact* code in  *release* mode causes an error.

#### Context

The Flutter documentation teaches us [how to work with WebSockets](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/web-sockets).

Let's use consider the *official* code example to work with WebSockets (I've modified it a bit to display the error in a `Text` Widget):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'WebSocket Demo';
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: title,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
  });

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  final _channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
    Uri.parse('wss://echo.websocket.events'),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Form(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Send a message'),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 24),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: _channel.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
                } else {
                  return const Text('listening...');
                }
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _sendMessage,
        tooltip: 'Send message',
        child: const Icon(Icons.send),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  void _sendMessage() {
    if (_controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      _channel.sink.add(_controller.text);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _channel.sink.close();
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

#### The problem

If you run the above code snippet on MacOS in debug mode, it will work correctly. However, If you build the app using `flutter build macos`, you'll get this error:

```
SocketException: Failed host lookup: ‘...’ (OS Error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known, errno = 8)
```

[image]

#### What I tried

1. > [SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1) with flutter app on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65458903/socketexception-connection-failed-os-error-operation-not-permitted-errno-1?rq=1)
   > which said to add this
   > `<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key> <true/>`
2. > [SocketException: Failed host lookup: ‘...com’ (OS Error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known, errno = 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66063913/socketexception-failed-host-lookup-com-os-error-nodename-nor-servname-p)
3. > [ssh: Could not resolve hostname [hostname]: nodename nor servname provided, or not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252294/ssh-could-not-resolve-hostname-hostname-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-n)
4. Turned off my FireWall.
5. Made sure there's an active Internet connection.

#### Question

**Why does the above snippet work in Debug mode, but not in release mode when running `flutter build macos`?**

##### Note

Running

```
flutter doctor -v
```

says "no issues found".

Comment: Upvoted for the clarity of the question, including all code/details/what's attempted and `flutter doctor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said it works on debug mode, but not on release mode, so I suspect you have already added the entitlements to the debug profile, but you probably forgot to add it to the release profile.

Under `macos` > `Runner` directory, find both "DebugProfile.entitlements" and "Release.entitlements" files:

[image: folder structure screenshot]

Add this section to both files:

```
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: Is there anything else you could think of? I have the same issue like described but the entitlements for Debug and Release are equal :(